# Number of words in vocabulary gensim word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

How can I print the number of words in the model's vocabulary for gensim Word2Vec?

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
```

I have tried

```
len(model.wv.vocab)
```

But I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\word2vec.py", line 4, in <module>
    len(model.wv.vocab)
AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'wv'
```

And this

```
len(model.vocab)
```

And it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\word2vec.py", line 4, in <module>
    len(model.vocab)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 645, in vocab
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it for newer versions on [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/99240/gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format)

```
len(model.vectors)
```

Comment: Even more generally, you can just do `len(model)`. Once your model is in fact a data object like `KeyedVectors` (and not something like the algorithm object `Word2Vec`, which would *contain* an internal `KeyedVectors` in its `.wv` property), you can do more things directly on it. It may be useful to use a more-distinct variable-name in such cases, like `kv_model`. And the list-of-words in it is in `kv_model.index_to_key`, because each word is a key for looking up the vector (or other per-key properties).